# Question word usage

Tags: language-evolution

According to the Reading Teachers Book of Lists, of the 100 most popular (used most often) spoken words in American English, the question word "what"(there are six question words that are commonly used in journalistic and other research: what, who, where, when, why and how) comes in thirty-seventh. Only one other question word, "who," makes the list, and it is eighty-seventh (so who is certainly not on first).  Why is what so popular?

Comment: 'Popular' is loaded. 'What' is obviously needed more often than say 'who'. It is used to attempt to determine what the issues / facts / details / ramifications of a matter or object are.

Comment: @edwin Right. I further defined popular in the question.

Comment: Which country's "Reading Teachers Book of Lists"? Who compiled it, what sources did they use, do they mean written or spoken, and which dialects of English are they talking about? And _popular_ means there has been a poll taken -- of whom? by whom? when? in what language(s)? Etc? Find out where the list came from and you'll find your answer.

Comment: The list was compiled by The W.E.B. DuBois Learning Center in Kansas City, U.S., which among its numerous endeavors compiles lists of "popular" words. It has its list of the first 100 most popular, and a list of the second hundred most popular, and then the third, and so on. I found no information on the site about their research methods or sources. Are you implying that "what" is not 37th most popular word in American English? http://www.duboislc.org/ED-Watch/wordlist.html

Comment: Yes. It appears on the W.E.B. DuBois Learning Center's list, but that is not an ISO standard. And what they mean by "popular" may be "common", but who knows?

Comment: Just based on a 59-second Google search, it appears that "what" can be used in a few contexts that aren't questions (or related to implies questions), e.g., "what a shame" and "what will be, will be". "What if" is implicitly short for "What would happen if ..." (or similar), but it may have transcended that mold, and become a phrase unto itself — "What If?" is the 12th result in my search for "what". (OK, that's cheating — it's https://what-if.xkcd.com.) Maybe the other wh– words aren't as flexible.

Comment: @Scott That may partially explain what's frequency. But the other question words can be used in non-question contexts also: I know why (where, when, how) you did it. It would be interesting to know the ratio of the non-question what to the question what.

Comment: Well, my point is that “I know ______ you did it” means “I know the answer to the question «______ did you do it?»” ***(implied question)***. But I agree that I haven’t done nearly enough research or investigation to post my thought as an answer.

Comment: @scott You're point is well taken. I think though that all the question words can be used in none question/answer contexts. Who, for example, can function as a relative pronoun, where no question or answer is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Where, when, why and how deal with the places, times, reasons and methods "whos" do things and "whats" happen.  This means that generally there will be a "what" or a "who" associated with each, but likely not the inverse.  Of course that only explains why "who" and "what" get on the list in the first place.  The reason "what" is ahead would seem to me to be directly related to the disproportionatly smaller number of "whos" (people) there are to "whats" (basically everything else under the sun).